# PHP if value equals "this" -> do nothing, else add =' before and ' after

Tags: php, sql, forms, if-statement

I've hit a crossroad while coding up a search filter, and I don't even know the verbiage for a practical search.

I have a form that generates values based on SQL, then I'm using php on the display page to format these values for an SQL search. My desired behavior is to include an option in the html form that bypasses this specific filter to show all products. My previous solution has been to include IS NOT NULL as the value of one of the options, however that was before I generated form data based on the SQL values.

Here's my desired behavior as best I can explain (this is not my code, just a coded-explanation).

```
if $productnamesort == " IS NOT NULL" -> do nothing (leave value as " IS NOT NULL")  
if $productnamesort != " IS NOT NULL" -> append characters before and after the value (=' before and ' after)
```

So I need to format the output of $productnamesort to essentially be one of two things

1) " IS NOT NULL"
2) ='$productnamesort'

Just for a little more detail, here are the relevant pieces of code.

## Form Input

```
    <select class="selectinput" name="filter_product_name">
    <option value=" IS NOT NULL" selected>All Products</option>
    <?
    $r = mysql_query("select product_name from products");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){
    echo "<option value='{$row['product_name']}'>{$row['product_name']}</option>";}
    ?>
    </select>
```

## Current PHP Formatting (where I need some help)

```
$productnamesort = $_POST[ 'filter_product_name' ];
```

I know there are a variety of ways to address this issue, if anyone has something more efficient I'm eager to learn.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing it like this.

You could make your form like this:

```
<select class="selectinput" name="filter_product_name">
<option value="all_products" selected>All Products</option>
<?
$r = mysql_query("select product_name from products");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){
echo "<option value='{$row['product_name']}'>{$row['product_name']}</option>";}
?>
</select>
```

Then you could do something like this for the query:

```
<?php
 if($_POST['filter_product_name'] == 'all_products') {
   // Query like Select * from products
 } else {
   // Query like SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = '".$_POST['filter_product_name']."'
 }
```

I know that my last part is pseudo-code, but you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good thing to use `mysql_*` functions, but you can do the following :

```
$productnamesort = $_POST[ 'filter_product_name' ];
if ($productnamesort != " IS NOT NULL")
  $productnamesort = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($productnamesort)."'";
```

A better solution is to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` functions (mysql_* is deprecated and will be removed in future releases).

You can easily follow the examples given in the official documentation for [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare) or [PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).